How fast is taking the quotient of a group by a subset?
Let $G$ be a finite group, and assume you have some computational representation of $G$ that allows efficient iteration through its elements, constant-time checks for equality between elements, and constant-time multiplication of a pair of elements. I'm thinking of something like the full multiplication table (e.g. [[0,1],[1,0]] for the cyclic group of order $2$). Let's also assume that we can compute inverses in $G$ in constant time (but we can find all of these anyway in $\Theta(|G|)$ time using the formula $(g^i)^{-1} = (g^k)^{-1}g^{k-i}$ for $i \in [1..{k-1}]$ after finding $k$ for which $(g^{k})^{-1}$ has already been found). Let's also assume we know the identity of the group.
Let $S$ be a set of elements of $G$. I want to determine the complexity of computing $G/N$, where $N:=\langle S^G\rangle$ is the normal subgroup generated by $S$, in terms of $|S|$ and $|G|$.
Here's one approach:

Compute the set $S^G := \{gsg^{-1} : g \in G, s \in S\}$ in $\Theta(|G||S|)$ time.
Compute the set $N := \langle S^G\rangle$ by doing a search starting at the identity and for each $x \in N$ found, exploring $xy$ for $y \in S^G$, visiting each $x$ only once. This takes $\Theta(|N||S^G|)$ time.
Partition $G$ into cosets of $N$ by at each step removing some element $g$ from the pool of $G$ elements and then removing all of $gN$, until the pool of elements is empty. Record the index of the coset each element belongs to. All of this takes $\Theta(|G|)$ time.
By choosing representatives of each coset, the quotient group operation can be computed in constant time as new_operation(x, y) := representative_of[coset_of[G_operation(x, y)]], for any representatives $x$ and $y$.

Note that when $|N||S^G|$ is small, we don't need to even use the quadratic time required to list out the $(|G|/|N|)^2$ entries of the multiplication table.



The last partitioning step shows that computing $N$ is just as good as computing $G/N$, assuming we're already using $\Omega(|G|)$ time. So an equivalent question is: How fast can we compute normal closures?
Is this $\Theta(|G||S| + |N||S^G|) \subseteq O(|G|^2)$ time optimal? And can we say any tighter bound than $O(|G|^2)$ only in terms of $|G|$ and $|S|$? I recognize that there are many special cases, such as Abelian groups or groups where you already have a nice presentation or a permutation representation, where this algorithm or another algorithm will be especially fast, but I'm mostly curious about the worst case where $G$ is an arbitrary group multiplication table (even though I expect most computational group theory happens with smarter representations).

Your problem is two in one, and I suggest to split them. 1) efficient computation of normal closure. 2) efficient computation of quotient group by a normal subgroup.

As I mention, my problem is equivalent to computing the normal closure, since we can translate between the two in $O(|G|)$ time.

It looks like this can be done in $O\big(|G|\cdot\log (|G|)\cdot \alpha(|G|)\big)$ time, where $\alpha$ is the very slow-growing inverse Ackermann function--an upper bound is $O(|G| \log^2 |G|)$ time.
First, we can use a Union-Find data structure, something like this in Python:
class UnionFind:
    def __init__(self, objects):
        self.objects = objects
        self.parent = {obj:obj for obj in objects}
        self.size = {obj:obj for obj in objects}

    def find(self, x):
        # Amortized runtime: O(alpha(len(objects)))
        # Path splitting
        p = self.parent
        while p[x] != x:
            x, p[x] = p[x], p[p[x]]
        return x

    def union(self, x, y):
        x = self.find(x)
        y = self.find(y)
        if x == y:
            return
        if self.size[x] < self.size[y]:
            x, y = y, x
        self.parent[y] = x
        self.size[x] += self.size[y]

    def component(self, x):
        x = self.find(x)
        return {y for y in self.objects if self.find(y) == x}

Then we can use this to find the subgroup generated by a set:
def generated_subgroup(G, operation, e, X):
    # (G, operation) is a group with identity e
    # X is a subset of G
    u = UnionFind(G)
    for x in X:
        if u.find(e) != u.find(x):
            for g in G:
                u.union(g, operation(g, x))
    return u.component(e)

Above, after x has run through some $x_1, \dots, x_n$, I claim that u has partitioned G into cosets of the generated subgroup $H_n=\left<x_1, \dots,x_n\right>$. For $n=0$ we have singleton partitions, which are cosets of the trivial subgroup $H_0=\left<\right>=\{e\}$. Then for an inductive step, we have two cases:

If $x_{n+1}\in H_n$ already, then $H_{n+1} = H_n$, and so we already have cosets of $H_{n+1}$. The body of the if statement is skipped.

Otherwise, $x_{n+1}\notin H_n$, and we enter the body of the if-statement. After the for g in G loop, the equivalence relation $\sim$ defined by u has $gx_{n+1}\sim g$ for all $g \in G$. It also already had $gh\sim g$ for all $g \in G$ and $h \in H_n$. Now for any $g \in G$ we have
$$
   g \sim gh_1\sim g h_1 x_{n+1}^{k_1} \sim g h_1 x_{n+1}^{k_1} h_2 \sim g h_1 x_{n+1}^{k_1} h_2 x_{n+1}^{k_2} \sim \cdots
$$
and so any arbitrary word $h'=(h_1 x_{n+1}^{k_1} h_2 x_{n+1}^{k_2}\cdots) \in \left<H_n, x_{n+1}\right> = H_{n+1}$ has $gh\sim g$. This shows that $\sim$ now includes the same-coset relation $\sim_{H_{n+1}}$. To show the opposite inclusion, note that all of the pairs $(g, gx_{n+1})$ added to $\sim$ certainly belong to $\sim_{H_n}$, and so the equivalence relation the pairs generate is included in $\sim_{H_n}$ as well because $\sim_{H_n}$ is an equivalence relation.


Now consider the runtime of generated_subgroup. Each time the body of the if statement passes, two previously-disjoint cosets get united, so the size of each coset doubles. Hence the if statement body can only run at most $\log |G|$ times. That body runs in $O(|G|\alpha(|G|))$ time, so overall we have $O(|X|\alpha(|G|) + |G|\log |G|\alpha(|G|)) = O(|G| \log |G| \alpha(|G|))$ time.
A similar procedure allows finding a small subset of generators for $G$:
def find_generators(G, operation, e):
    generators = []
    u = UnionFind(G)
    for gen in G:
        if u.find(e) != u.find(gen):
            generators.append(gen)
            for g in G:
                u.union(g, operation(g, gen))
    return generators

By similar reasoning as above, this returns a subset $G' \subseteq G$ with $|G'| \leq \log_2|G|$ and $\left<G'\right>=G$, and likewise takes $O(|G| \log |G| \alpha(|G|))$ time. We can use these generators to find conjugates:
def find_conjugates(G, operation, e, inverse, X):
    # (G, operation) is a group
    # e is the identity
    # inverse is a function that finds the inverse of an element.
    # X is a subset of $G$.
    generators = find_generators(G, operation, e)
    u = UnionFind(G) # relate conjugates
    for gen in generators:
        gen_inv = inverse(gen)
        for g in G:
            u.union(g, operation(gen, operation(g, gen_inv)))
    # Now all conjugates are related.
    # Relate all elements of X so that there is just one component
    # to worry about.
    x0 = next(iter(X)) # arbitrary element of X
    for x in X:
        u.union(x0, x)
    return u.component(x0)

The above also takes $O(|G| \log|G| \alpha(|G|))$ time. Now to tie everything together:
def normal_closure(G, operation, e, inverse, X):
    conjugates = find_conjugates(G, operation, e, inverse, X)
    return generated_subgroup(G, operation, e, conjugates)

Hence, normal_closure can be computed in $O(|G| \log|G| \alpha(|G|))$ time.
If we want to go on and compute the quotient, we can do something like this:
def quotient(G, operation, e, inverse, X):
    N = normal_closure(G, operation, e, inverse, X)
    elements = set(G)
    bins = []
    for g in G:
        if g in elements:
            gN = {operation(g, n) for n in N}
            elements -= gN
            bins.append(gN)
    to_representative = {}
    representatives = []
    for bin in bins:
        rep = next(iter(bin))
        representatives.append(rep)
        for x in in bin:
            to_representative[x] = rep
    def quotient_op(rep1, rep2):
        return to_representative[operation(rep1, rep2)]
    def quotient_inverse(rep):
        return to_representative[inverse(rep)]
    return representatives, quotient_op, to_representative[e], quotient_inverse

This takes a set G, constant-time functions operation and inverse, and a susbet X, and produces a new group on the set of representatives, with constant time functions quotient_opn and quotient_inverse, all in $O(|G|\log |G| \alpha(|G|))$ time. As mentioned in the question, we can make these constant-time functions without even reading the $|G|^2$ entries of the original multiplication table or explicitly producing the $|G/N|^2$ entries of the quotient multiplication table.
